# ruby script get JSON from RESTful web service

Tags: ruby, json, rest

I am trying to write a simple ruby script to collect an array of JSON objects from a RESTful web service.  I have read a lot of documentation that suggests I need to create an HTTP GET request, but I haven't seen an example of how to pass parameters to only return the objects I need. (I.e. I need to retrieve ONLY JSON objects with a particular name/value pair)

Essentially I am trying to query a database that can return information in JSON format, but I only want to select objects that meet certain criteria, and store that in an array.

I have been able to retrieve ONE JSON object, by looking at the NET requests in chrome developer tools when I manually search for one of these objects using a web GUI, but I cannot figure out how to generate a request for multiple objects.

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am new to both ruby and REST.

Thanks!

Comment: You want a REST library. Search around.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend viewing the presentations about REST API first and find some talks on Youtube:

- [API design and more](https://speakerdeck.com/u/jrom/p/api-design-and-more)
- [Implementing a RESTful API with Ruby](https://speakerdeck.com/u/josephruscio/p/implementing-a-restful-api-with-ruby)

Most useful gems at current moment:

- [rails-api](https://github.com/spastorino/rails-api)
- [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)
- [goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath)
- [sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com)

And don't forget `Grape`.

If you want to go deeper in the area, next books will help you with that:

- [APIs: A Strategy Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449308929)
- [REST in Practice: Hypermedia and Systems Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805829)
- [RESTful Web Services Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596801688)

Answer (score 0):

Using java/jpa with REST, we use a named query or a native query.  I would be surprised if Ruby did not have something similar.